# Sorting a poset?

Tags: language-agnostic, sorting, poset

There are a huge number of sorting algorithms out there, but most of them only work on totally-ordered sets because they assume that any two elements are comparable.  However, are there any good algorithms out there for sorting posets, where some elements are uncomparable?  That is, given a set S of elements drawn from a poset, what is the best way to output an ordering x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub> such that if x<sub>i</sub> ≤ x<sub>j</sub>, i ≤ j?

Comment: Isn’t this just topological sort?

Comment: @jleedev- You could do it with a topological sort only if you knew how every pair of elements in S compared with one another a priori; otherwise you'd have to spend O(|S|^2) time doing all the comparisons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a paper titled [Sorting and Selection in Posets](http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1532v1) available on arxiv.org which discusses sorting methods of order O((w^2)nlog(n/w)), where w is the "width" of the poset.  I haven't read the paper, but it seems like it covers what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  This looks very promising!

Answer (score 2):

[Topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) is well-suited to sorting a partially ordered set.  Most algorithms are O(n^2).  Here's an algorithm from Wikipedia:

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted elements
S ← Set of all nodes with no incoming edges
while S is non-empty do
    remove a node n from S
    add n to tail of L
    for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
        remove edge e from the graph
        if m has no other incoming edges then
            insert m into S
if graph has edges then
    return error (graph has at least one cycle)
else 
    return L (a topologically sorted order)
```

There's a [helpful video example](http://www.showme.com/sh/?h=qovixPc). Most Unix-like systems have the `tsort` command.  You could solve the video's brownie example with `tsort` as follows:

```
$ cat brownies.txt
preheat bake
water mix
dry_ingredients mix
grease pour
mix pour
pour bake

$ tsort brownies.txt
grease
dry_ingredients
water
preheat
mix
pour
bake
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with selection-exchange sort. That's O(n^2) and I don't think you'll do better than that.